# why does the compiler give a warning for unused function?

Tags: c, function

I have just written a sample program to understand the working of functions in C. I declared a function in C and call it during my programs execution. However my compiler gives me a warning saying unused function. My code looks like this :

```
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <stdio.h>

 int test_function(x);
 int main(){

     int x;
     char letter[] ={"HAAA"};
     char cmpre[] = {"AHD"};
     int value;

     for(int i=0; i<4;i++)
     {
       if(letter[i] == cmpre[i])
         { 
           x=0;
         }
     }

     int test_function(x)
        {
          if (x==0)
          {
            printf("the letters are the same");
          }
         return value;
        }

   printf("To check if the letters are the same go to the function");
   test_function(x);

   return 0;
   }
```

The program seems to execute fine but I get a warning in the fourth line where I declared the function in the start of the program. The warning is :

```
  Multiple markers at this line
- parameter names (without types) in function declaration [enabled by 
 default]
- Unused declaration of function 'test_function'
```

I think the way I am calling my function is not right. Could somebody please help me. Thnak you in advance.

Comment: write the function outside of main function

Comment: @RaghuSrikanthReddy: But then you can't use the local variable `value` in `test_function`. (The code uses non-standard nested functions.)

Comment: `int test_function(x);` isn't a valid function declaration. `x` isn't a type.

Comment: The whole code is somehow misguided. I think `test_function` should be a regular (non-nested)  function for string comparison. `x` isn't initialised to 1 and `value`, which is used only inside `test_function` for no good reason, also is uninitialised.

Comment: @MOehm :Could you please be kind enough to tell me how could I rectify it? I would be thankfull..

Comment: Note that if `cmpre[]` holds only 2 chars not 3, the letter by letter comparison would be UB since `compre[3]` falls outside its range.

Comment: Even if you *had* initialised `x=1` (ref @MOehm) the comparison would fail since it only takes one letter match to set `x=0`

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: nested functions are non-standard C and I only know (of) the [GNU extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html) for this. As such anything I claim here may well be untrue in another implementation. My recommendation is that you just don't use them at all.

Your nested `test_function` is shadowing the global declaration. So the `test_function` you declared above `main` is never called, because the call inside `main` refers to the nested function. Hence, you get a warning.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare  int test_function outside of main

for example.

```
 int test_function(int x)
```

and then call the function in main.

```
value = test_function(x)
```

This is what your code should look like:

```
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <stdio.h>

 int test_function(x)
        {
          int value = 0;

          if (x==0)
          {
            printf("the letters are the same");
          }
         return value;
        }

 int main(){

     int x = 0; 
     char letter[] ={"HAAA"};
     char cmpre[] = {"AHD"};
     int value = 0; // unused

     for(int i=0; i<4;i++)
     {
       if(letter[i] == cmpre[i])
         { 
           x=0;
         }
     }

   printf("To check if the letters are the same go to the function");
   test_function(x);

   return 0;
   }
```

Note that if you dont need a return value you could make the function void.
And initialize your variables. You may search hours to find such a error

Comment: `value` isn't declared inside `test_function`; this won't compile.